# android studio won't install on linux with sudo or without sudo

Tags: android, linux, android-studio

i have download android-studio-ide-141.2117773-linux.zip and extract it then go to this folder:

```
~/Program/Andr/android-studio/bin
```

and run it:

```
$ ./studio.sh
```

Then it looking for sdk path and found it somewhere(that i had it before):

I choose standard and click next then next and here click on Finish:
[image]

Then i've got this error:
[image]

And these lines:

```
There is nothing to install or update.
The following SDK component was not installed: extra-google-m2repository
```

It's the contents of /home/mrg/Program/android/adt/sdk:

```
$ ls
add-ons      docs    platforms       samples         system-images  tools
build-tools  extras  platform-tools  SDK Readme.txt  temp
```

Now i run it with sudo (also i run it with inside root terminal):

```
$ sudo ./studio.sh
```

Now path is different:
[image]

Click finish then i face to this error:
[image]

And these lines:

```
There is nothing to install or update.
The following SDK components were not installed: extra-android-m2repository, extra-google-m2repository and platform-tools
```

It's the content of:

```
$ sudo ls /root/Android/Sdk
add-ons  platforms  SDK Readme.txt  tools
```

Also i change permissions of /root/.android and /home/mrg/.android

Is there any idea how can i install Android Studio on linux Mint?
it's my linux info:
[image]

ALso it's my SDK manager:
[image]

And when i create a project it's shows this windows and nothing happen:
[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a package manager: https://paolorotolo.github.io/android-studio/

Comment: @JaredBurrows Actually it's not different.i have tried it. it only download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/1.3.0.10/android-studio-ide-141.2117773-linux.zip (that i have download it manually) and put inside /opt then make shortcut in menu. the problem starts after run android studio

Comment: You didn't use a package manager. The whole point of using one is to automate the installation process to avoid the issues you are seeing now.